# node can't find modules when using process substitution in bash script

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I have a command that I normally would run in the `scripts` section of my `package.json`, but the problem is that `npm run` uses `sh`, which has no support for process substitution.

I need process substitution because I would like to pass args to the result of `flow-remove-types index.js`, and can't do that with a pipe.

So I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=./node_modules/.bin:$PATH

case $1 in
  start)
    node <(flow-remove-types index.js) ${@:2}
  ;;
  works)
    flow-remove-types index.js | node
  ;;
esac
```

---

Now the issue is that when I use process substitution, node can't find the installed modules. Running with the `works` command in the case statement that runs `flow-remove-types index.js | node` has no problems with finding the modules, but when I run the command `start` with process substitution. I get the following stack trace

```
module.js:457
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'moment'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/dev/fd/63:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Why wouldn't node have access to the modules installed in `node_modules`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that when you run:

```
flow-remove-types index.js | node
```

then `node` tries to find the `node_modules` directory in the current working directory because it doesn't know where the script is located - it gets it via STDIN.

But when you run:

```
node <(flow-remove-types index.js)
```

then `node` doesn't get the script on STDIN, but in a file like `/dev/fd/63` or something like that, and it gets its filename as the command line argument.

Try this to see what it gets evaluated to:

```
echo node <(flow-remove-types index.js)
```

It then probably tries to find the `node_modules` directory in `/dev/fd` and it's not there.

Maybe running something like this would help:

```
NODE_PATH=`pwd`/node_modules node <(flow-remove-types index.js)
```

I can't test it because for me running:

```
node <(cat app.js)
```

doesn't work even if `app.js` doesn't require any modules.

Comment: You were right about the `/dev/fd`, the NODE_PATH fixed the module problem but now it can't find files in the same directory, and finally, weird that `node <(cat app.js)` doesn't work for you.

Comment: To be honest I'm just being stubborn about creating an output file, and at this point now that I know the file is being run from `/dev/fd` I don't think I can fix my new issue without using absolute paths.

Comment: @AR7 as for the files in the same directory, I would assume that `__dirname` is now `/dev/fd` or something. maybe you can pass the path to your script as an argument or in the environment variable, like: `NODE_PATH=`pwd`/node_modules CORRECT_PATH=`pwd` node <(...)` and then use the `process.env.CORRECT_PATH` in your script. As for the `node <(cat app.js)` not working I am very surprised. Maybe it's a bug. Node 6.5.0 and 5.12.0 give me errors on Ubuntu. which shell scripts it works. very strange.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to be messing with all that when I can just make an output file haha. It was just an experiment, and it's much more hassle than it's worth. Thanks for all your help though :)